# Ionic / Cordova : Upload image from phone's gallery

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like the user to be able to either take a picture or select an image from his phone's gallery.

I successfully manage to take a picture and get the **imageURI**.

I'm using Genymotion as emulator since i need to access to some functionalities such as camera. I know there are some other solutions. It is a little bit hard to debug while emulating but this is the only way i found to access to the camera for now. Therefor i can't see what is going on on the second part (Select an image from Gallery).

```
$scope.uploadPopup = function() {
    var uploadPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: "Edit profile's picture",
        templateUrl: 'templates/partials/upload-img.html',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: '',
                type: 'button-energized icon-center ion-ios7-camera',
                onTap: function(e) {

                    // e.preventDefault() will stop the popup from closing when tapped.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Getting camera');
                    Camera.getPicture({
                        quality: 100,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                    }).then(function(imageURI) {
                        alert(imageURI);
                        $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
                    }, function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });

                }
            },
            {
                text: 'From gallery',
                type: 'button',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Getting gallery');
                    Camera.getPicture({
                        quality: 100,
                        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                    }).then(function(imageURI) {
                        alert(imageURI);
                        $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
                    }, function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
            }
        ]
    });
};
```

Service :

```
app.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }

}]);
```

Is it the correct way to do? Any hints or ideas?

**UPDATE :**

When i add :

```
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```

to the first function (take a picture from camera). It does not work any more. While without (using the default one probably) it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i added the sourceType instead of using the default sourceType(CAMERA)

```
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```

It was not working anymore so i guessed something was wrong here.

**The correct syntax is :**

```
navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```

OR (with different option) :

```
navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
```

Not sure why "navigator.camera" and not "Camera", i'm guessing "Camera" is an alias of "navigator.camera".

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is on the right track, like you said it is hard to tell without being able to test it on a device. So i can help you there. go grab the intel xdk https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools. import your ionic project, then make an account. after you log in go to the test tab and push your app to a test server. Then install the intel app preview on your phone/tablet (is on android and ios). open the app, log in, and hit server apps at the bottom, you will see your app and be able to run it on your phone. You can also use the intel xdk to run an app on your phone with live debugging. Hope this helps! cheers!

Here is the code for my ngCordova plugin:

```
//opens up the phones camera in order to take a picture
        //requires module ngCordova and the method $cordovaCamera
        //sets Data.Image to a base 64 string
        $scope.takePhoto = function () {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                var options = {
                    quality: 100,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: false,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
                    targetWidth: 800,
                    targetHeight: 1100,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };
                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {

                    $scope.image = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData;
                }, function (err) {
                    // error
                });
            }, false);
        };
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that and give my feed back.

Comment: It is kinda odd. I launch the app from the intel app preview. But the picture from camera doesn't work at all. I'm not sure how it is working but i suppose since the app is launched from their server that it doesn't have access to those functionalities. Just a supposition.

Comment: It is even more odd now. It is working on Genymotion only. I tried to build the application from the intel xdk and download it from my Mobile and install it. The API is perfectly called and i get all the data i need. But the camera button does not pop up the camera as it does on Genymotion.

Comment: hmm, that is strange. Well i had some problems with the cordova plugin for camera, and the intel xdk plugin for camera, so i used the ngcordova module camera and it worked great. you can find it here http://ngcordova.com/. Also on ios i had to make the encodingType a PNG to get it work. I will add my code i used for my plugin above

Comment: also dont forget to add ngcordova to your modules and include the js files. hope this helps!

Comment: I finally managed to make it work. I use "navigator.camera" instead of "Camera" (which might be an alias of "navigator.camera"). Anyway thank you so much for your time.